# Adding $n-1$ first terms of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let's define a real - valued sequence:
$$a_k = kp^k,$$
where $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p \in (0,1]$.
I would like to find the sum of first $n-1$ terms of $a_k$, that is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kp^k.$$
How can I do it?

Comment: Let $S $ denote the sum you want. Consider $S-Sp $ and use geometric sum formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

You probably know that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\tag{1}$$ Can you manipulate this sum to get $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kx^k$$ ? Try playing around with differentiation.

---

*Edit for completion:*

*Differentiating both sides of $(1)$ yields* $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^{k-1}=\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{x(1-x)^2}\tag{2}$$ *(the series starts at $k=1$, because the first term is $0$) multiplying $(2)$ by $x$ yields the desired sum* $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^{k}=\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{(1-x)^2}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thank you! I knew that I can use differentiation is series but I didn't realize that finite sums are much more simpler and the same technique works :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what you use if you don't know anything about differentiation -_-

---

Let $$S=p+2p^2+3p^3+\cdots+(n-1)p^{n-1}.$$

Then $$Sp=p^2+2p^3+\cdots+(n-2)p^{n-1}+(n-1)p^{n}$$

By subtracting the 1st equation with the 2nd equation we get

$$S(1-p)=p+p^2+p^3+\cdots+p^{n-1}-(n-1)p^n=\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}-1-(n-1)p^n$$

Comment: The expression for $S(1-p)$ is not right, it should be $$\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}-1-(n-1)p^n$$ You need to subtract $1$, since $$\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}=\color{red}{1}+p+p^2+\ldots+p^{n-1}$$

Comment: Oh yeah thank you